# Log4j, logging, eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j

How do I create logging files for this info using log4j?

```
    // Convert to proper logging statement 
    System.out.println("Using folder:   [" + path + "]");
    System.out.println("Using city:  [" + city + "]");
    System.out.println("Using list: [" + listType + "]");
```

Comment: Did you check out tutorials like https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html, http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/ or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm? I thinks it's useless to just anwer with `      log.debug("Using folder:   [" + path + "]");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Maven, add the log4j package to your `pom.xml`. Otherwise you can download the log4j jar and add it to your `classpath`. Create a config file for log4j called `log4j.properties` where you can add details like this:

```
log = /usr/home/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Then just reference the logger in your code:

```
final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(yourclassname.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to this.

1. Configure log4j 
    
    You will need a configuration file.  This is where you can define the format of the messages as well as where the log statements go, like to a specific file as you mentioned.  This can be either a log4j.properties file, or log4j.xml file.  This configuration file needs to be placed on your source path in order for it to be picked up.  A good starting place for this is in your source folder if you're using eclipse (your question is tagged with eclipse, so I assume that's what you're using).  Alternatively, you can place it in a different project folder and add that project folder as a source folder in your build path.  For information on how to create the XML configuration file, refer [here](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat).
2. Use log4j in your Java code

   A good way to use log4j is to configure a private static logger in every class.  For your example:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
   import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

   public class MyClass {
       private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);

       public static void main(String[] args) {
         logger.info("An info Message!");
         logger.error("An error Message!");
       }

   }
   ```